# absolute audio synchronization

Tags: synchronization, gstreamer

I would like to synchronize my computer with an external camcorder recording so that I can know exactly (to the millisecond) when certain recored events happen with respect to other sensors logged by the computer.  One idea is to playback short sound pulses or chirps every second from the computer that get picked up by the microphone on the camcorder.   But the accuracy of a simple cron job playing a sound clip is not precise enough.  I was thinking of using something like gstreamer, but how does one get it to playback a clip at precisely a certain time according to the system clock?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the starting time of your camcorder, you can derive the time for any time of the video from the video stream that is captured. You don't need to do any of this. Every frame has a timestamp associated with it in a container and the exact time can be known. All you need is to note the starting wall time.

EDIT:Another way to do it would be as follows: if you have a clock you trust, can you put that in the camcorder's path? So you always have a measure on the video itself.

Comment: The issue I'm trying to solve is how to accurately sync the camcorder's clock with the clock on the computer.  I suspect that the clocks will also drift a bit with respect to one another since they are using different crystals.  I'm playing with scheduling a sound to play off the computer at a known time (or times) then I can correspond the recorded sounds with the transmitted times and map the clock drift and offset of the camcorder's timestamps with respect to the computer.

Comment: Unless you are looking for absolute ns and micro second accuracy, the drift should really be very small and built over very large periods of time.  How do you ensure you computer clock does not drift incorrectly?  I think you are over engineering it. If I have a video i know the exact timestamp offset of every frame of the video from the starting point of the video upto millisecond accuracy. So why should not just measuring starting time be enough? If you are not convinced I have put another mechanism in my original answer.

Comment: but how to you propose to measure the starting time of the camcorder when it is not directly connected to the computer?    And I suppose your idea of putting a clock in view of the video is analogous to my idea of putting a ticker within earshot of the recorder ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt at solving this.  I've modified one of the gstreamer python tutorial commandline playbin (example 2.3) from http://pygstdocs.berlios.de/pygst-tutorial/playbin.html to repeatedly play a sound file at a defined interval synced with the system clock.

I've made sure that the pipeline uses the system clock instead of the default clock from the sink, and disabled the pipeline from setting the base times of the elements.
Then with the file is done playing, it seeks back to the beginning, and the base time is manually set so that the sink will wait to play the buffer at the next epoch.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, os
#import time, thread
import glib,gobject
import pygst
pygst.require("0.10")
import gst

class CLI_Main:

  def __init__(self):
    self.player = gst.element_factory_make("playbin2", "player")
    fakesink = gst.element_factory_make("fakesink", "fakesink")
    self.player.set_property("video-sink", fakesink)
    bus = self.player.get_bus()
    bus.add_signal_watch()
    bus.connect("message", self.on_message)

    # use the system clock instead of the sink's clock
    self.sysclock = gst.system_clock_obtain()
    self.player.use_clock(self.sysclock)

    # disable the pipeline from setting element base times
    self.player.set_start_time(gst.CLOCK_TIME_NONE)
    # default tick interval
    self.tick_interval = 1;

    self.tick_interval = float(sys.argv[1])
    filepath = sys.argv[2]
    if os.path.isfile(filepath):
      self.playmode = True
      self.player.set_property("uri", "file://" + filepath)
      current_time = self.sysclock.get_time()
      print current_time
      play_time = (current_time/long(self.tick_interval*gst.SECOND) + 1) * long(self.tick_interval*gst.SECOND)
      print play_time
      self.player.set_base_time(play_time)
      self.player.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)
      print "starting"

  def on_message(self, bus, message):
    t = message.type
    if t == gst.MESSAGE_EOS:
      # compute the next time the sound should be played
      current_time = self.sysclock.get_time()
      play_time = (current_time/int(self.tick_interval*gst.SECOND) + 1)*int(self.tick_interval*gst.SECOND)

      # setup the next time to play the sound and seek it to the beginning
      self.player.set_base_time(play_time)
      # seek the player so that the sound plays from the beginning
      self.player.seek(1.0, gst.FORMAT_TIME, gst.SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH, gst.SEEK_TYPE_SET, 0L, gst.SEEK_TYPE_NONE, 0L)   
      # make sure that the player will play
      self.player.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)
      #self.playmode = False
      print play_time

    elif t == gst.MESSAGE_ERROR:
      self.player.set_state(gst.STATE_NULL)
      err, debug = message.parse_error()
      print "Error: %s" % err, debug
      self.playmode = False


mainclass = CLI_Main()
loop = glib.MainLoop()
loop.run()
```

sorry if the code is hacked and messy; I am still new to python.